# Remove specific box with jquery

Tags: jquery

When you click Add a box. It adds a box with a deletlistbtn.
Right now it removes all boxes with the same name/class/var.
But i want the button to only delete the box/list its in.
Can anyone tell me wich code i should use to accomplish that?

Right now i use this code;

```
  $('.deletelistbtn').live('click', function() {
        $(redbox).remove();
    });
```

this is my entire code http://jsfiddle.net/XsCAN/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(this).parent().remove()` or something similar. (`$(this).parent().parent().remove()` - depending what are you going to accomplish)

Comment: thank you for your answer! $(this).parent().parent().remove() works!

Answer (score 1):

Unless Im missing something I think you want

```
$('.deletelistbtn').live('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Just like the `.removebutton` code.

http://jsfiddle.net/XsCAN/1/

Comment: Thank you for your solutions, it doesnt remove the whole box though.

Answer (score 1):

While I realise that you've already accepted an answer, I feel it's worth pointing out that there is a slightly easier approach than navigating the DOM using `...parent().parent()...`, [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) makes this easy by working upwards through the DOM automatically/natively to find the relevant element:

```
$('.deletelistbtn').live('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('.redbox').remove();
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/XsCAN/6/).

It *does* however work according to the element type, `id` or `class` (so `.closest('.redbox')` works, `.closest(redbox)` doesn't).

Comment: I appreciate it a lot! I didn't know you could use closest for this. And this teaches me i should wait a few minutes befor accepting. Sorry but thanks a lot!